# Does an actual insurance policy exist to cover multiple MacBook Pros used by school students?

Tags: macbook-pro

I need to insure 18 MacBook Pro 15 retinas and 18 MacBook Pro 13 retinas for a school making a large purchase where the students are permitted to take the laptops home for homework. Does an insurance policy exist that will cover this? Both en masse or individual policies will work since parents will need to pay for their share of the policies. However, since parents are paying, the policy premium needs to make sense.

Comment: You can get insurance to cover just about anything. Have you spoken to an insurance agent?

Answer (score 1):

One of the companies I used in the past and still recommend today is [Safeware](http://www.safeware.com/Education.aspx).

They have solutions specifically for edu customers covering both in house staff and the student population at large.  Their claim service is pretty good - having done quite a few myself.

Answer (score 0):

Four years ago our kids' school issued over 900 iPads. All students were provided with a compulsory protective case and the iPads went to/from home each day, and all students were allowed to have them at home during school holiday periods.

The school had a policy which covered the iPads for broken screens. The policy covered the first time a student broke the screen, and for each subsequent break the parents had to contribute half of the cost of repair (or opt to arrange their own repair at their own cost).

This year they issued Surface Tablets to the senior high school students (about 350) to replace their iPads. These are also covered by insurance.

Obviously with 36 MacBooks your coverage will be different, and the economies of scale aren't comparable, but the point is that you'd be able to get some sort of coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get devices insured in bulk. Although most companies will have you sign up within 30 days of purchasing the devices - but there may be a policy within your school for property damage.

Alternatively, you could use a third party warranty/insurance company such as [Protection](http://www.useprotection.me)

Disclaimer: I work at Protection. Send me a message if you still need coverage, we work with new, used, and refurbished devices.